# Can this SQL pivot query be parameterized to avoid SQL injection?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-injection

I have a need to use `pivot` to create a result set, but part of the issue is the columns (i.e. `dbo.TrainingType.Title`) are a result of user input. I've thought about using a function to filter out potential keywords, or clean the user's input, but I'm not confident this is truly reliable.

Here's the query:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Title) 
            FROM dbo.TrainingType c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT * 
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT u.UserID, tt.Id AS TrainingId, u.DisplayName, tt.Title, te.[ExpireDate]
                    FROM dbo.vw_Users u
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.TrainingEmployee te ON u.UserId = te.UserID
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.TrainingType tt ON te.TrainingID = tt.Id

                ) x
                pivot
                (
                    max(ExpireDate)
                    for Title IN (' + @cols + ')

                ) piv'

execute(@query)
```

Any way to rewrite this to accomplish the same result?

```
UserID | TrainingId | DisplayName | List | Of | Titles | As | Columns
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1            John Doe      A     B    C        D    DROP TABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, dynamic SQL cannot be parameterized.   Parameters can only be used to replace values in a SQL Query, not columns or other object names.

Comment: Understood and thank you for your answer. I was hoping there was a creative way to write a query that produced the same results without dynamic sql.

Comment: The good news is that the sql that you posted isn't at risk of sql injection anyway, because it's not taking any user input.   The `@cols`variable is populated from your database, so as long as you haven't let malicious values get stored in your table in the first place, this code is safe from injection.

Comment: Well the `@cols` originate from user-entered data. They create their own training types. I'll have to do my best to clean the input unless I can figure something else out. Or feed the data to the app differently and construct everything with javascript.